# Dynamic Imports Based on this.props in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS app, I have node_modules (js files) for themes for certain elements on the page. I want to load only the files I need this based on this.props.theme for the component. How/where would I do this in my component. Basically, if I have a bunch of files for themes:

```
theme-red.js
theme-orange.js
theme-yellow.js
theme-green.js
theme-blue.js
theme-purple.js
theme-violet.js
theme-pink.js
theme-rainbow.js
```

In the props, I would `this.props.theme`passed in and then load in `require(theme-${this.props.theme}.js)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `import` function:

> const theme = await import(`./{path-to-the-files}/theme-${this.props.theme}.js`)

It would be good to include this in the `componentWillMount` function of the component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import
https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports